# How to get in a JCombox from the selectedItem the id?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox

I hava a class StageDAO like this:

```
public class Stage{

    public int stageID;
    public String label;

    public Stage(ResultSet rs) {
            try{
                this.stageID=rs.getInt("StageID");
                this.label=rs.getString("Label");
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
     }
}
```

I have a method in a class StageDAO, where i get Data from Database, like this:

```
public class StageDAO{
Connect connectdb;

public StageDAO(Connect connectdb){
    this.connectdb=connectdb;
}

public Vector retrieveAll() {

    ResultSet lobjRS=null;
    Vector lobjList=new Vector();
    Connection lobjConnection = null;
    Statement lobjStatement=null;        
    Stage lobjStage = null;

    try{
        lobjConnection = this.connectdb.getConnection();
        lobjStatement = lobjConnection.createStatement();
        lobjRS = lobjStatement.executeQuery(
             "SELECT * FROM Stage order by sortkey");
        while(lobjRS.next()){
            lobjStage = new Stage (lobjRS);
            lobjList.add(lobjStage);                
        }
      }catch(){}
   }
}
```

in my GUi class i have this:

```
StageDAO lobjStage= new StageDAO (connectdb);
Vector<Stage> stageList = lobjStage.retrieveAll();//Here i have the information 
of stageID  and  stagelabel

private JComboBox lcbstage;

public void initialize(){
    lcbstage= new JComboBox();
    for(int i=0; i<stageList .size();i++){
    lcbstage.addItem(stageList.get(i).label);
    }
}
```

But know if i select in my Gui the stage, i want to know the stageid.
I don't know how to get the stageid of the selected stagelabel ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - `}catch(){}`  That would not even compile.  Please stop wasting our time with 'something like' the code used.

Comment: Ok sorry, i doesnt knew this

Comment: Don't apologize if you don't intend to follow the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Add the whole item to your `JComboBox`, not just the label, and create a `toString()` method which will return just the label:

```
public String toString(){
    return this.label;
}
```

[`JComboBox`'s `addItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object) takes an object and then converts it to a string for display, so when you do `getSelectedItem()` the whole object, `id` and `label` and everything else, will be returned.

```
public void initialize(){
    lcbstage= new JComboBox();
    for(int i=0; i<stageList .size();i++){
    lcbstage.addItem(stageList.get(i));//this line changed
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i think you mean like this: lcbstage = new JCombobox(stageList).  But know my combobox shows like this: packagename.Stage

Comment: Ok i have do like you say. At it works well. But if i want to know the id ... i do lcbstage.getSelectedItem() and i get the label. but i want to have the stageid

Comment: To get the I'd, do `lcbstage.getSelectedItem().id` after putting in the whole item as I do in the above code.

Comment: To your first comment, did you implement toString like above?

Comment: I doens't have this option. I have do this like you say. But i can only use the string operations.

Comment: yes i implement the toString in the class Stage like you say

Comment: Did you try doing what I suggested 2 comments ago?

Comment: yes i have put the whole item like you say lcbstage.addItem(stageList.get(i));//this line changed -- The to String i have implementate like you say in my Class Stage -- And know i see in the in the gui the label and not the stageid--thats fine. but if i do lcbStage.getSelectedItem() i have only the string operations, i can't do lcbStage.getSelectedItem().id

Comment: Have you tried type casting it to an object of class Stage? That is, `((Stage) (lcbstage.getSelectedItem())).id`?